# Cannot Set Header To GET request For 3rd party URL

Tags: node.js, express

I am Redirecting to 3rd party URL in node js but before redirecting I want to add header to that url.

Scenario is I am submitting form from URL xyz and then receiving form in backend then processing the form, after processing the Form I want to redirect to URL abc with this header res.set({ 'X-API-TOKEN' : "my token", });

but I am not able to do so

```
 res.set({ 'X-API-TOKEN' : "my token", });
 res.redirect(`${process.env.M_api_url}/funds/purchases/payment/${funds_transfer_ref}?redirect_url=myurl`);
```

can anyone help me out?

Comment: You cant set a header for a third party url where you have no controll over the server.
With one exception: Proxy the request through a server you controll and do with the response what ever you want

Comment: okay means there's no way for setting header for 3rd party URL, thank you

Comment: As i wrote, you can proxy the request through a server you control. So can you set headers and manipluate requests/response as you want. There are packages for node.

Comment: yes I know that but in my scenario it doesn't work, because i can not manipulate the response

Comment: But you can rund node, and node has ready-to-use packages for proxing requests.

Comment: ready-to-use packages like axios, fetch?

Comment: No. "proxy" packages like [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy)

Comment: okay , actually my scenario is the above URL which I want to redirect to is a payment gateway URL so I cannot HIT this URL in backend, what I want is I want to load this URL on web browser but before loading URL to web-browser I want to add header to this request then load it on Web Browser.

Comment: Not possible. *perhaps* with xhr, but i dont think so.

Comment: ok let me try it with xhr